# How to test the mysql-router failover?

Tags: mysql-innodb-cluster, mysqlrouter

I implemented mysql innodb cluster using three servers "test-1", "test-2", "test-3". Out of which my test-3 is the master-node. My cluster setup is working as expected, now I would like to test the mysql-router failover. Kindly provide some useful insights, how to set it up and test whether the mysql-router failover is working or not.

Thanks in advance!